# passing asynctask objects to other activity

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

I want my list to be displayed in new activity, but when I click the button I get the results in the same page, how do I get the results to be passed to new activity?
Button:

```
myList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

          new AsyncTask().execute("");

        }
    });
```

onPostExecute:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                //Arrays.sort(avstand);
                Intent intent = new Intent();

                minValue = getMinValue(avstand);

                if(result== false){

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else {
                    Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.rad, myListe);
                    list.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Use constructor or Pojo classes...

Comment: I would make a global/singleton class that holds static objects/variables.  You can just set them and get them anywhere in your application

Comment: Why don't you just start the next activity and have that run the the AsyncTask?